# React duplicating a rendered div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, reactjs

I am learning React by migrating my project from js/jquery to react.

In my project I have a function that duplicates a div block(with changed ids and data) on button click.

So for example I have a div remade in react and a button that should add a new div on click:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="expense-block" id="expense-block-0" data-block="0">  </div>
        <button
             type="button"
             className="btn btn-primary custom-add-button add-row"
             onClick={this.addRow}><i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    )
}
```

When I click the button it should duplicate the div with new ids. The result should be:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="expense-block" id="expense-block-0" data-block="0">  </div>
            <div className="expense-block" id="expense-block-1" data-block="1">  </div>
            <button
                 type="button"
                 className="btn btn-primary custom-add-button add-row"
                 onClick={this.addRow}><i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        )
    }
```

How can I achieve this in React without using 0 js/jquery? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to have a state in your react component for adding divs

class AddNewRow extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       customDiv: ['div1']     // set initial state with one div
    }
  }

  addNewRow(){
    let cDivs = this.state.customDiv;
    cDivs.push('newDiv')
    this.setState({customDiv: cDivs })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        // iterate the customDiv array 
        this.state.customDiv.map((cdiv, i) => {
          <div className="expense-block" key={cdiv} id="expense-block-`${i}`" data-block={i}>></div>
        })
        <button onClick={() => this.addNewRow}>Add Row</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" in the addNewRow method when I try to access state

Comment: @Dominykas55 Change `addNewRow` to arrow function

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition to the answer above.
Don't mutate the state!
Create a new array from this.state.customDiv

```
addNewRow(){
    let cDivs = [...this.state.customDiv];
    cDivs.push('newDiv')
    this.setState({customDiv: cDivs })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an array containing all the ids and data, and then, render '  ' via array.map()
Then, addRow will just add an element in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can render an array

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.state={ numOfRows: [1]}
}
addRow() {
 this.setState({numOfRows: this.state.numOfRows.concat([2])})
}
```

and then in the render function

```
render() {
     return (
        { this.state.numOfRows.map(e=> (<div className="expense-block" id={"expense-block-" + e} data-block={3}>  </div>))
        }
        <button
             type="button"
             className="btn btn-primary custom-add-button add-row"
             onClick={this.addRow}><i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    )
}
```